# Compound object in HTML <button> value attribute

Tags: html, json

If for some reason it were mandatory to associate a <button> with more than one value, is there a good way to do it?  For example ...

```
CSV: 
  <button value="Lancelot,Grail,blue">Answer</button>
JSON: 
  <button value="{'name':'Lancelot','quest':'Grail','color':'blue'}">Answer</button>
```

In the absence of a *good* way to do it, is there a *traditional* way?

**Edit: another use case**

Server M, the producer of the HTML, knows the user's current location and favorite genres, movie names, nearest theater, and next showtime.  Server F knows how to query various 3rd party servers about how to get from point A to point B in order to arrive by time T.  The user knows only the movie names: click *Drag Me to Hell*, and get the route.  Server M *could* generate a form for each movie, with a single button showing the name of the movie and multiple hidden fields with the start and end locations and desired arrive-by time, but that would require a lot of repeated code. Every one of these one-button mini-forms would have the same method and action and the same hidden input field structure.  Styling would be a collection of mini-forms rather than a collection of buttons, so FIELDSET and LEGEND are unavailable (because HTML forbids nested forms).  Putting the parameters into the button's value attribute would be much tidier.

Comment: I am sorry but I am unable to understand the reason for doing such a thing. You could use a radio button for selection & have a button to accept that choice.

Comment: I'd guess just pick any delimeter that you know won't occur naturally within a value.

Comment: @shahkalpesh, consider the case where (1) the html producer has a map which associates a key with a compound object; (2) the button-click consumer has neither the map nor the key, but is able to interpret the compound object; and (3) the user to whom the button is presented knows the key but does not necessarily know the values for the compound object.  

Is there a way to associate a compound object with a radio button?

Answer (score 1):

Well if you have to have a button element, why not use JavaScript to set a bogus property:

```
$('mybutton').compoundValue = { ... json ... };
```

and then reading the 'compoundValue's during form submit, etc.

Though really you might want to consider a group of checkboxes or some other form bits for what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Alas, if the client has disabled JavaScript, the degradation is fairly graceless. +1 for the suggestion, though.

Comment: For complete graceful degradation, you'll have to go with separate form elements or forcing your server-side to parse comma-separated values. Also, it is now quite rare for people to disable JavaScript and certainly not unheard of for webapps to require it.

Comment: @Eric Wendelin, count your blessings.  A significant fraction of the enduser-population of one of my clients is using the AOL browser.